# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.CustomHtmlFormatter

Tags: java, xml, maven, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am new to cucumber parallel execution. I need to do the parallel execution of cucumber TestCases  with cucumber plugin "cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin". 
When I run a pom.xml file It throws an error. Please let me know my mistake.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.127 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestRunner.Parallel01IT
[ERROR] initializationError(TestRunner.Parallel01IT)  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< ERROR!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.project.CustomHtmlFormatter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.CustomHtmlFormatter
```

Below are the project structure.

[image]

POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Steps</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    .....
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- COPY RESOURCES TO TARGET/ -->

            <resource>
                <directory>../../Cucumber5/src/test/resources/features</directory>

            </resource>
        </resources>
        <!-- RUN EACH CUCUMBER FEATURE FILE AS A FORK -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <glue>
                                <package>com.project.Steps</package>
                            </glue>

                            <outputDirectory>../../Cucumber5/src/target/generatedTestSources/</outputDirectory>
                        <featuresDirectory>../../Cucumber5/src/target/classes/</featuresDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutputDir>../../Cucumber5/src/target</cucumberOutputDir>


                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <name>json</name>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                    <name>com.project.CustomHtmlFormatter</name>
                                    <extension>html</extension>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                            <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
                            <strict>true</strict>

                            <monochrome>true</monochrome>

                            <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
                            <namingScheme>pattern</namingScheme>
                            <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                            <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>

                            <!-- Specify a custom package name for generated sources. Default 
                                is no package. -->
                            <packageName>TestRunner</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>





               <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
<!-- RUN ALL CLASSES CREATED BY cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin IN PARALLEL -->
        <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>acceptance-test</id>
             <phase>integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                 <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                 <includes>
                    <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
                 </includes>
             </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
         </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After running the pom.xml file below Parallel01IT.java file
generated.

```
package TestRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        strict = true,
        features = {"E:/workspaceTAAP/Cucumber5/src/target/classes/tester.feature"},
        plugin = {"json:E:/workspaceTAAP/Cucumber5/src/target/1.json", "com.project.CustomHtmlFormatter:E:/workspaceTAAP/Cucumber5/src/target/1.html"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags = {},
        glue = {"com.project.Steps"})
public class Parallel01IT {
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.CustomHtmlFormatter`: where is the class in your Project?

Comment: But com.project.CustomHtmlFormatter: is plugin. So it should get from maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

error occurring because class `CustomHtmlFormatter` is not into `com.project` package. and package `com.project` is not present into you project. create the proper package and classes first.